# Should TTY phone numbers be hyperlinked as normal numbers?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility

Most site developers know to use the `tel:` syntax for phone number links to enable easy mobile dialing:

```
<a href="tel:555-867-5309">(555) 867-5309</a>
```

Should the same be done for [TTY numbers](http://www.abouttty.com)? Are there other or additional techniques that should be used for accessibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's enough (Maybe add some description that will say it's TTY number). A deaf person can click link in same way that non-deaf person can do so if you are not using sounds on your website it's sufficient.

Setting TTY on your phone: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207033

If you plan making your site accessible for blind people too then I would suggest you reading https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/

Comment: Using tty on your phone: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207033. You just have to set it up on your phone and it work just voice call

Answer (score 3):

According to the [RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-1) :

> The terminal
> addressed can support **any** electronic communication service (ECS),
> including voice, data, and fax.  The URI can refer to resources
> identified by a telephone number, including but not limited to
> originators or targets of a telephone call.

For accessibility, you should indicate within the content of the link that the phone line is a TTY.

> ```
> <a href="tel:555-867-5309">TTY: (555) 867-5309</a>
> ```

Comment: In my case, "TTY" was in a heading above the number. It stands to reason that it should be *in* the link for the case of someone scanning anchors with a screen reader.

Comment: @isherwood Exactly. Always having link understandable outside of context (which is also useful when scrapped by search bot)